# Cannot get names after sorting in Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to sort user based on their ages and get only names after sorting:

```
private final List<User> userList = Arrays.asList(
        new User(1, "Michael", "Robert", 37, "JP"),
        new User(2, "Mary", "Patricia", 11, "NL"),
        new User(3, "John", "Michael", 7, "FR"),
        new User(4, "Jennifer", "Linda", 77, "ES"),
        new User(5, "William", "Elizabeth", 23, "US"),
        new User(6, "Sue", "Jackson", 11, "IT"),
        new User(7, "Robert", "Tommy", 37, "GB")
);
```

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Sample sample = new Sample();
    sample.test();
}

public void test() {
    userList.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(User::getAge)
                    .thenComparing(User::getFirstName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .forEach(System.out.println(User::getFirstName));

}
```

However, there is an error "Cannot resolve method 'println' in 'PrintStream'" for `println` method even if I invalidate cache. I also try with method reference, but now solved. How can I fix the problem with stream?

Comment: You need to use a full lambda, not a method reference: `.forEach(v -> System.out.println(v.getFirstName()));`

Comment: Even better, don't collect, do `map(User::getFirstName).forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: The `collect` step is pointless. Just use `userList.stream() .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(User::getAge) .thenComparing(User::getFirstName)) .forEachOrdered(v -> System.out.println(v.getFirstName()));`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Seems good idea, yes I would use it. Thanks amigo. You may also update answer.

Comment: @Holger No Amigo Holger, other approaches with map seems better

Comment: @Jonathan what do I need to update in my answer?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Amigo, could you pls explain when I can use method reference instead lambda?

Comment: @Jonathan I added an explanation for why what you were doing is wrong

Comment: You can use `map` or not, whatever you like. That doesn’t change the fact that collecting into a `List` is obsolete.

Comment: @Holger I think you are referring for this question or should I always avoid from collecting via `.collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Avoid it when all you’re doing with the list, is chaining just one single stream operation. Then, you can simply perform one stream operation in the first place.

Comment: @Holger  Thanks a lot, voted up. As I am new in stream, could you explain a little bit more the situations when I should avoid or not?

Comment: When you collect into a `List`, you’re forcing the implementation to allocate storage for all elements and to process all of them and add them to the list. Depending on the actual operation you’re chaining afterwards, the storage might be unneeded, as processing can be done on-the-fly or it might even be unnecessary to process all elements to get the final result. In either case, collecting into an intermediate list consumes resources without benefit.

Comment: @Holger Perfect explanations, thank you so much Holger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
.forEach(System.out.println(User::getFirstName))
```

Is not correct.

[`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) expects a `Consumer` here, which means that for this to work as written `System.out.println` would need to take `Supplier` as a parameter (`User::getFirstName`) and return a `Producer`. Which, of, course, is not how `println` works.

You'll have to use a lambda instead, like

```
.forEach(u -> System.out.println(u.getFirstName()))
```

Here `u -> System.out.println(u.getFirstName())` is the `Consumer` `forEach` expects.

Even better, you're not doing anything with the result except printing, which means you don't need to `collect`. Instead you could obtain a stream of first names with `map`, and then print those (so you can use method references instead of a lambda).

```
public void test() {
    userList.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(User::getAge)
                    .thenComparing(User::getFirstName))
            .map(User::getFirstName)
            .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);

}
```

Note: using `forEachOrdered` instead of `forEach` because [the latter is nondeterministic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) so it *may* print things out-of-order, which would defeat the purpose of sorting the elements in the first place.